# How can I "Save As" in Workgroups for Windows (for Emacs)?

Tags: workgroups

In [`Workgroups for Windows (for Emacs)`](https://github.com/tlh/workgroups.el), is there a "Save As" function?

I know there is a create function, but that first does a "C-x 1" it seems, so it destroys my layout, before it saves it;)

I can recreate my layout manually and then update afterwards, but I must be missing something;)

Comment: Can you please add some context? What does this have to do with Emacs?

Comment: I added a description for the `workgroups` tag that explains.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Workgroups, instead of Workgroups2;)